# Prove that $G$ is an open set

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume that $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Define $G$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $G=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid a<x<b\ \text{and}\ y>f(x)\}$. Prove that G is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$

I have the open ball $V_r(x,y)$, and I pick a point $(x',y')$ in the open ball. Then I want to show $(x',y')\in G$. I get $a < x'< b$, but I get stuck with how to show $y'>f(x')$, that I can only have $y'>f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider the function
$$
g\colon (a,b)\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},\qquad
g(x,y)=y-f(x)
$$
Is the function $g$ continuous? Then $G=\{(x,y)\in(a,b)\times\mathbb{R}:g(x,y)>0\}$, so…